# Ace code editor not allowing my menu to show up top

Tags: html

I have the following code which shows the Ace code editor in the div, but my main menu isn't showing up. Any ideas as to why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Editor</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: black;
    }

    #editor {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    ul.topnav {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0 20px;    
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
        width: 920px;
        background: #222;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        background: url(topnav_bg.gif) repeat-x;
    }

    ul.topnav li {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;  
        padding: 0 15px 0 0;
        position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/
    }

    ul.topnav li a{
        padding: 10px 5px;
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: left;
    }

    ul.topnav li a:hover{
        background: url(topnav_hover.gif) no-repeat center top;
    }

    ul.topnav li span { /*--Drop down trigger styles--*/
        width: 17px;
        height: 35px;
        float: left;
        background: url(subnav_btn.gif) no-repeat center top;
    }

    ul.topnav li span.subhover {background-position: center bottom; cursor: pointer;} /*--Hover effect for trigger--*/

    ul.topnav li ul.subnav {
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute; /*--Important - Keeps subnav from affecting main navigation flow--*/
        left: 0; top: 35px;
        background: #333;
        margin: 0; padding: 0;
        display: none;
        float: left;
        width: 170px;
        border: 1px solid #111;
    }

    ul.topnav li ul.subnav li{
        margin: 0; padding: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #252525; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
        border-bottom: 1px solid #444; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
        clear: both;
        width: 170px;
    }

    html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a {
        float: left;
        width: 145px;
        background: #333 url(dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a:hover { /*--Hover effect for subnav links--*/
        background: #222 url(dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat 10px center; 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Main Menu -->
    <div id="main_menu">
        <ul class="topnav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Resources</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- source editor -->
    <div id="source_file" style="background-color: red; width: 100%; position: relative; min-height: 1px; height: 200px;">
        <pre id="editor"></pre> 
    </div>

    <script src="ace-builds-master/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        var gui = require('nw.gui')
        var win = gui.Window.get();

        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/lua");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add higher `z-index` for `.subnav` (say `10000`) and to push down `source_file` div to not overlay your menu